# Unable to load asset application.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, assets

I have to modify a RoR project. All the javascripts are in the public/assets folder and my work is to move them in the app/assets/javascripts folder.

But when I try to import my javascript in my view with that : `<%= javascript_include_tag "application"%>` the result in code is the folowing :

```
<script src="/javascripts/application.js">
  {"status":"ERROR","message":"404 not found"}
</script>
```

Currently here is what [I've got in my folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjVyy.png)

I haven't modify the application.js. The file contain these lines :

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

I also modify my `config/application.rb` to add this line :

```
require 'sprockets/railtie'
```

I don't know why I have a 404 not found. In all the tutorials that I read it looks like that all I have to do is to put my JS in `app/assets/javascripts` and use `javascript_include_tag` to access it. But I suppose that some configurations lines are missing but I can't figure out which.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Which mode you are running?, production mode or development mode?

Comment: @VtrKanna I'm in production mode